# C#: Getting Error: "A generic error occurred in GDI+" When trying to copy imagebox.Image into memory stream. This stream is not being saved to file.

Tags: c#, image, runtime-error, memorystream

I am getting an odd error with `Image.save(Stream, Format)`.

I tried looking around on here for a solution but everyone seems to think the error is from file permissions. That can't be it in my case case the Stream isn't going into a file. My code is below:

```
MemoryStream Stream = new MemoryStream();
this.Image_Box_1.Image.Save(Stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
TI.AlbumCover = Stream.ToArray();
Stream.Close();
```

`TI.AlbumCover` is a `byte[]`.

Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem might be?

EDIT:

Ok, so I worked it out. The original file could sometimes come from a jpg file, sometimes from a byte array (part of an id3 tag). The problem was that when the image came from the file, I was closing the stream after creating the image box image. While the image remained visible, the data was no longer available.

Since I also later needed to overwrite that jpg file, I could not simply leave the filestream for it open so I left the rest of my code the same and changed the code to read from the jpg to the following:

```
FileStream FS = new FileStream(File, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);//Read in the jpg file
Image IMG = Image.FromStream(FS);//Create an image from the file data
MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream();
IMG.Save(MS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);//Save the image data to a memory stream
byte[] temp = MS.ToArray();//Copy the image data to a byte array
//close the streams
MS.Close(); 
FS.Close();
return temp; //was originally returning an image
```

Then after executing this code I change the code that placed the image into the image box to:

```
try
{
    if (this.m_V2Tag.AlbumCover != null)
        this.Image_Box_1.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(this.m_V2Tag.AlbumCover));
    //changed code
    else
    {
        MemoryStream temp = new MemoryStream(this.getFolderJpg()); //create a memory stream from the byte[]. This stream can safely be left open.
        this.Image_Box_1.Image = Image.FromStream(temp); // create image and assign it to the image box
    }
}
catch
{
    this.Image_Box_1.Image = null;
}
```